# SASS/COMPASS: Unable to use the ligthen/darken function

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have been using SASS/COMPASS 6 months, great stuff!
Today, I wanted to use the `lighten()/darken()` functions, but I get the following error message:

```
error style.scss (Line 220 of breakpoints/_base.scss: Invalid CSS after 
"lighten": expected "{", was "(#800, 20%);")
```

Here is how I call it within my .scss file:

```
li {
lighten(#800, 20%);
}
```

I feel I am missing some declaration or import, as it seems the function isn't being recognize, but I haven't found a thing talking about this online.

Any suggestion/tip is most welcome!

Comment: Can you post your current function code please?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. That is the thing then. I haven't coded the lighten function. From my understanding of [the documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method), it was provided by the SASS library. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AnindyaBasu OP is correct, `lighten()` is a standard SASS function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not setting the lightened color as a style.  You probably mean:

```
li {
  color: lighten(#800, 20%);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'll put that one on the overwork.
Thank you very much. You ended one hour of roaming around.